# In App Receipt Validation with Swift returns code 21002

Tags: swift, receipt-validation

I've sent my data to the server in hopes of validating a receipt and am getting a malformed response (21002). The json that I send to iTunes validates in JSONlint.org and looks like the following:

```
{"receipt-data":"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_kvTvyRgKF9B080GZL0zmZSR93EEtsEyPBqO6PVrSePmQeoK\/vS1k9\/uZdd5XuaQyISrVWC2DpjU6eC_wLlLvqnQwUAIBBgIBAQRI85FUTb1tsun7ZcnNO9jP0Ya3Jpr\/njNS_P11OJ9GD7gbIArIWohrpkX0VN\/kH6KDHUeVPRkug\/\/pQm7pF6LQxPZs_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_p9LOfHOgo\/FLAgaLLVmKAWqKRrk5Aw30oLtfT7U3ZrYr78mdI7Ot5vQJtBFkY\/4w3n4o38WL\/u6IDUIcK1ZLghhFeI0b14SVjK6JqjLIQt5EjTZo\/g0DyZAla942uVlzU9bRuAxsEXSwbrwCZF9el_0mRzuKhETFeGQHA2s5Qg17I60k7SRoq6uCfv9JGSZzYq6GDYWwPwfyzrZl1Kvwjm_8iCOt7WRQRn3M0Lea5OaY79_Y_7Mqm_6uvJt_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_3CYHi\/2e8_2_Q9aNYS3k8NwWcwHWNKNpGXcUv7lYx1LJhgB\/bGyAl6mZheh485oSp344OGTzBMtf8vZB_wclywIhcfNEP9Die2H3QuOrv3ds3SxQnICExaVvWFl6RjFBaLsTNUVCpIz6EdVLFvIyNd4fvNKZXcjmAjJZkOiNyznfIdrDdvt6NhoWGphMhRvmK0UtL1kaLcaa1maSo9I2UlCAIE0zyLKa1lNisWBS8PX3fRBQ5BK\/vXG_tIDHbcRvWzk10ee33oEgJ444XIKHOnNgxNbxHKCpZkR_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_4fyaRvDRTes58Y4Bhd2RepQcjtjn_UC0VVlhwLX7EbsFKhT4v8N6EGqFXya97GP9q_hUSSRUIGayq2yoy7ZZjaFIVPYyK7L9rGJXgA6wBfZcFZ84OhZU3au0Jtq5nzVFkn8Zc0bxXbmc1gHY2pIeBbjiP2CsVTnsl2Fq\/ToPBjdKT1RpxtWCcnTNOVfkSWAyGuBYNweV3RY1QSLorLeSUheHoxJ3GaKWwo\/xnfnC6AllLd0KRObn1zeFM78A7SIym5SFd\/Wpqu6cWNWDS5q3zRinJ6MOL6XnAamFnFbLw\/eVovGJfbs_Z3e8bY\/6SZasCAwEAAaOBrjCBqzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH\/BAUwAwEB\/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUiCcXCam2GGCL7Ou69kdZxVJUo7cwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUK9BpR5R2Cf70a40uQKb3R01\/CF4wNgYDVR0fBC8wLTAroCmgJ4YlaHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcHBsZS5jb20vYXBwbGVjYS9yb290LmNybDAQBgoqhkiG92NkBgIBBAIFADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEA2jIAlsVUlNM7gjdmfS5o1cPGuMsmjEiQzxMkakaOY9Tw0BMG3djEwTcV8jMTOSYtzi5VQOMLA6\/6EsLnDSG41YDPrCgvzi2zTq_GGQTG6VDdTClHECP8bLsbmGtIieFbnd5G2zWFNe8_0OJYSzj07XVaH1xwHVY5EuXhDRHkiSUGvdW0FY5e0FmXkOlLgeLfGK9EdB4ZoDpHzJEdOusjWv6lLZf3e7vWh0ZChetSPSayY6i0scqP9Mzis8hH4L_aWYP62phTKoL1fGUuldkzXfXtZcwxN8VaBOhr4eeIA0p1npsoy0pAiGVDdd3LOiUjxZ5X_C7O0qmSXnMuLyV1FTCCBLswggOjoAMCAQICAQIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwYjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCkFwcGxlIEluYy4xJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFwcGxlIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BcHBsZSBSb290IENBMB4XDTA2MDQyNTIxNDAzNloXDTM1MDIwOTIxNDAzNlowYjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCkFwcGxlIEluYy4xJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFwcGxlIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BcHBsZSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA5JGpCR_R2x5HUOsF7V55hC3rNqJXTFXsixmJ3vlLbPUHqyIwAugYPvhQCdN\/QaiY_dHKZpwkaxHQo7vkGyrDH5WeegykR4tb1BY3M8vED03OFGnRyRly9V0O1X9fm\/IlA7pVj01dDfFkNSMVSxVZHbOU9\/acns9QusFYUGePCLQg98usLCBvcLY\/ATCMt0PPD5098ytJKBrI\/s61uQ7ZXhzWyz21Oq30Dw4AkguxIRYudNU8DdtiFqujcZJHU1XBry9Bs\/j743DN5qNMRX4fTGtQlkGJxHRiCxCDQYczioGxMFjsWgQyjGizjx3eZXP\/Z15lvEnYdp8zFGWhd5TJLQIDAQABo4IBejCCAXYwDgYDVR0PAQH\/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB\/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFCvQaUeUdgn_9GuNLkCm90dNfwheMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFCvQaUeUdgn_9GuNLkCm90dNfwheMIIBEQYDVR0gBIIBCDCCAQQwggEABgkqhkiG92NkBQEwgfIwKgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmFwcGxlLmNvbS9hcHBsZWNhLzCBwwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwgbYagbNSZWxpYW5jZSBvbiB0aGlzIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIGJ5IGFueSBwYXJ0eSBhc3N1bWVzIGFjY2VwdGFuY2Ugb2YgdGhlIHRoZW4gYXBwbGljYWJsZSBzdGFuZGFyZCB0ZXJtcyBhbmQgY29uZGl0aW9ucyBvZiB1c2UsIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIHBvbGljeSBhbmQgY2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBwcmFjdGljZSBzdGF0ZW1lbnRzLjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAXDaZTC14t_2Mm9zzd5vydtJ3ME\/BH4WDhRuZPUc38qmbQI4s1LGQEti_9HOb7tJkD8t5TzTYoj75eP9ryAfsfTmDi1Mg0zjEsb_aTwpr\/yv8WacFCXwXQFYRHnTTt4sjO0ej1W8k4uvRt3DfD0XhJ8rxbXjt57UXF6jcfiI1yiXV2Q\/Wa9SiJCMR96Gsj3OBYMYbWwkvkrL4REjwYDieFfU9JmcgijNq9w2Cz97roy\/5U2pbZMBjM3f3OgcsVuvaDyEO2rpzGU_12TZ\/wYdV2aeZuTJC_9jVcZ5_oVK3G72TQiQSKscPHbZNnF5jyEuAF1CqitXa5PzQCQc3sHV1ITGCAcswggHHAgEBMIGjMIGWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECgwKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEsMCoGA1UECwwjQXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMxRDBCBgNVBAMMO0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5AggYWUMhcnSc\/DAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBAKnNWp78s\/DqSbFvJPRKmKlyLOAF9ggqScx8akGGRd3fvhFyvkAU2KfkdKvvx6puVg6AFfzdZWU2DhAl1\/_W5FtJq\/8ZmCPeBjRKzT93i40kKKOErKwrrpk44oPL3oL4kiAFEHMGC1qmfiEahSRyQo0ALl4aPwSMKhk7yK3aVORgXucNedUwG8q7WCX\/qtheLqabHvgSvt9VU9T\/WDv4dEwIal_yOtsZ9i3\/cLouH9IU41b3HMUwD4azDC5eNk3ys\/iOcI4D7EXm9bn_Bl8mLFXJWveN68mv0f6CQvN5tXx1fWOzEW5BvQ5x\/ZUwElLmnPa05OUPBMZJveU56uo_q8g"}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? My Swift is as follows:

```
var receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL;
var receipt: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(receiptUrl, options: nil, error: nil)
var receiptdata:NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)


    var requestContents:NSDictionary = ["receipt-data": receiptdata];

    var jsonString:NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestContents, options:nil,error:nil);


    var dta:NSString = NSString(data: jsonString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    request.HTTPBody = dta.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) 

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    // send the request
    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```

Answer (score 2):

this code may help you:

```
func validateRecipt(){
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?

    var recuptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
    var receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL:recuptUrl!, options: nil, error: nil)!



    //https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var receiptdata:NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed)
    NSLog("%@",receiptdata)
    var payload:NSString = "{\"receipt-data\" : \"\(receiptdata)\"}"
    var payloadData = payload.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var err: NSError?

    request.HTTPBody = payloadData

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:
        {data, response, error -> Void in
            var err: NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

            if(err != nil) {
                println(err!.localizedDescription)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
            else {
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    println("Recipt \(parseJSON)")
                }
                else {
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println("Recipt Error: \(jsonStr)")
                }
            }
    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your URL encoding. I had the same problem and it is how I got it fixed in Swift 2.3:

```
extension String {
    // correct URL encoding
    var URLEncoded: String {
        let allowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~"
        let allowedCharSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: allowedCharacters)
        let encodedString = self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedCharSet)
        return encodedString ?? self
    } 
}
```

Then use `yourReceipt.URLEncoded` before verification.

Answer (score 1):

Something is corrupted with your base64 receipt data. I tried using `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(_:options:)` to decode that string directly, as well as `NSData(base64EncodedString:options:)`, and they return nil if you don't pass `.IgnoreUnknownCharacters`.

I tested the rest of your code on a receipt I got from an App Store app, and it works fine, so it must just be the receipt data — try generating a new receipt.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and discovered the `+` in the Base64 encoding where being replaced by spaces on their journey to my server. Encoding them properly in the postdata (as `%2B`) solved the problem.